# MapBox/Google Map Api - Find Street Intersections

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapbox, android-mapview

I need to use a `Map Api` in my `android` app where `user` can define a path, A to B. How to find/count all street intersections(2 or more street crossed here) in between point A and B?

i. User will choose A and B

ii. it will return all street intersections points in between A and B

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Mapbox Directions API, and setSteps() to true, you'll receive intersection information as part of the step information. See [the documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#routestep-object) for more details.